# How did Hermione know that Lupin hadn't taken his potion?

Tags: harry-potter

In Chapter Twenty of *Prisoner of Azkaban* Lupin suddenly transforms into a werewolf:

> Harry could see Lupin's silhouette. He had gone rigid. Then his limbs began to shake.
>
> "Oh my –" Hermione gasped. "He didn't take his potion tonight! He's not safe!"

I don't see any indication in the story that Lupin had not taken the potion that night. So how did Hermione know this?

Comment: Because he's turning were?  If someone I know is taking allergy meds to deal with a dusty workplace, and suddenly he turns up one day sneezing, it's not a stretch to deduce he forgot to take his meds.  Don't forget that Hermione is the smart one.

Comment: I believe Snape said Lupin didn't take his portion so he bring one for Lupin when he enters ? So everyone hears that, and the trio knock Snape to hear Sirius's story. => just Hermione remember

Comment: @DavidW The potion doesn’t prevent the transformation. It just lets him keep his mind while in wolf form.

Comment: @someoneuseless Indeed, you are correct. I must have forgotten that part.

Comment: "I’m able to curl up in my office, a harmless wolf..." The werewolf form is not something I would describe as a wolf; I guess I read that as a physical difference in the transformed shape as well as a mental one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer couldn’t be simpler:

## it’s because Snape says so.

---

In *Chapter 19: The servant of Voldemort*, when Snape walks in revealing himself from under Harry’s invisibility cloak, he is carrying a goblet of the Wolfsbane potion that Lupin hadn’t consumed that night.

> Snape was slightly  breathless, but  his face  was  full of suppressed triumph. “You’re  wondering, perhaps, how  I  knew  you  were  here?”  he  said, his eyes  glittering.  “**I’ve  just  been to  your office, Lupin. You forgot to take  your potion tonight, so  I  took a  gobletful along**. And very  lucky  I did… lucky  for me,  I  mean.  Lying  on  your desk was a  certain map. One  glance  at it told me  all  I needed to know.  I  saw  you running  along  this passageway  and out of sight. 
>    <sub>*Chapter 19: The Servant of Voldemort*</sub>

It is clear that Hermione was scared because without the potion, Lupin wouldn’t be *a calm werewolf laying curled up in his office* but rather a fully fledged dangerous beast. And the reaction she gets from Sirius after that confirms that they *should* be very afraid of what's to come.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the potion needs to be taken once a day in the week preceding the full moon. If one is missed, then the full effect of the potion is lost.

> It makes me safe, you see. As long as I take it in the week, preceding the full moon, I 
>   keep my mind when I transform… I’m able to curl up in my office, a harmless wolf, and wait for
>   the moon to wane again.

The phrasing here is a bit unclear, and could be interpreted multiple ways. One could be that it must be taken within a seven-day period, preceding the full moon, the other (which is the intended interpretation) is that it must be taken *daily* in the seven day period, preceding the full moon.

> Wolfsbane Potion is a very recent discovery; if taken regularly once a day in the week prior to the full moon, it results in the werewolf keeping his mind when he transforms

[Source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Magic/Wolfsbane_Potion)

The sequence of events also gives us a rough time frame for how long Lupin had been with Black, Harry, Hermione and Ron. At the beginning of Chapter 17, the sun is just beginning to set, and half way through Chapter 20 was when they all re-emerged from the Whomping Willow, implying a decent chunk of time had passed.

The final clue though, is Sirius' reaction, who had a *lot* of experience with Lupin's Transformations (emphasis mine):

> A cloud shifted. There were suddenly dim shadows on the ground. Their party was bathed in
>   moonlight.
>
> Snape collided with Lupin, Pettigrew, and Ron, who had stopped abruptly. **Black froze. He flung
>   out one arm to make Harry and Hermione stop.**
>
> Harry could see Lupin’s silhouette. He had gone rigid. Then his limbs began to shake.
>
> “Oh, my —” Hermione gasped. “He didn’t take his potion tonight! He’s not safe!”
>
> **“Run,” Black whispered. “Run. Now.”**

Again, Hermione is switched on. She is piecing together several factors here:

- Lupin is a werewolf, that needs to take the Wolfsbane potion once a day, leading up to the full moon.
- They had spent a decent chunk of time in the Shrieking Shack.
- The fact that Sirius is scared, means something is *very wrong*.

Comment: *Sirius is scared*, this happens after Hermione says "He [Lupin] didn't take the potion tonight". I'm completely lost. I don't see anything in this that addresses *How Hermione knew that Lupin hadn't taken his potion?* . I'm DV since it isn't addressing the question. **PS: Check my answer**

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. The first two bullets have no bearing on whether he had taken the potion or not. As for Sirius, Hermione said it before Sirius told them to run. And it would only replace the question with “How did Sirius know?”